# Joomla API for lightbox?

Tags: joomla-api, joomla-3.4

Does Joomla 3.4 has any standard API for showing a lightbox container.  The idea is to show a view inside a lightbox container on a button click.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the API code like below

```
JHtml::_('behavior.modal', 'some_id_of_model');
```

Now your link to open the model

```
<a class="btn btn-primary some_id_of_model" title="title" href="url of the content" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}">Open Model</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `<?php JHtml::_('behavior.modal'); ?>` to your template's index file and call the modal box (lightbox) using this code

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" rel="{size: {x: 700, y: 500}, handler:'iframe'}" class="modal"> Open Lightbox </a>
```

If you do not see anything then check once, as if you used bootstrap template or css then by default `modal` class is given as `display:none`. So remove that display none property and then check for ti.

Comment: Exactly same answer is given by @Nagarjun on May 21.

Comment: Not at all, he hasn't used ** `class="modal"`** , which is faar more important for modal box. 
@SahilPurav you better watch answers very clearly, then try to take any action.