# Joomla 4 API for lightbox

Tags: joomla-4.x

I'm trying to upgrade my site to Joomla 4.
In Joomla 3 I used "JHTML::_('behavior.modal');" to display a link to an image inside a lightbox. As also explained in this question: [Joomla API for lightbox?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10032/joomla-api-for-lightbox)

Since this method is removed in Joomla 4, this no longer works. In the API docs I have found it is suggested to use bootstrap modal, but that does not work for link to images.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it as follow:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Layout\LayoutHelper;

HTMLHelper::_('bootstrap.modal');

?>

<?php
$modalData = [
        'selector' => 'uniqueIDName',
        'params'   => [
            'title'  => 'yourTitle',
            'footer' =>  htmlMarkup
        ],
        'body' => htmlMarkup
    ];
?>
<?php echo LayoutHelper::render('libraries.html.bootstrap.modal.main', $modalData); ?>
```

All the variables you can use:

```
/**
 * Layout variables
 * -----------------
 * @var   string  $selector  Unique DOM identifier for the modal. CSS id without #
 * @var   array   $params    Modal parameters. Default supported parameters:
 *                             - title        string   The modal title
 *                             - backdrop     mixed    A boolean select if a modal-backdrop element should be included (default = true)
 *                                                     The string 'static' includes a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.
 *                             - keyboard     boolean  Closes the modal when escape key is pressed (default = true)
 *                             - closeButton  boolean  Display modal close button (default = true)
 *                             - animation    boolean  Fade in from the top of the page (default = true)
 *                             - url          string   URL of a resource to be inserted as an <iframe> inside the modal body
 *                             - height       string   height of the <iframe> containing the remote resource
 *                             - width        string   width of the <iframe> containing the remote resource
 *                             - bodyHeight   int      Optional height of the modal body in viewport units (vh)
 *                             - modalWidth   int      Optional width of the modal in viewport units (vh)
 *                             - footer       string   Optional markup for the modal footer
 * @var   string  $body      Markup for the modal body. Appended after the <iframe> if the URL option is set
 */
```

Comment: Stack Exchange loves it when answerers also improve the quality of the question around the same time as answering.  This is indicated by [the Explainer badge](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/badges/91/explainer)  Please suggest an edit on the question which improves the English and makes any other helpful refinements.

Comment: @mickmackusa not sure of understand what you want me to do. The question is very clear for me so far.

Comment: There are typos in the asked question such as "suggested **t** use bootstrap modal" and "but that does **nog** work".  This is a great chance to pretty-up the question.  Can the title be improved? Can the body be improved? Can additional relevant tags be added?